# React Native (Android)- app appears twice on "Open with" list

Tags: android, react-native, expo, auth0

I am developing a react native app with Auth0 support. When a user opens the android app, an auth0 login page opens in the browser and upon successful signing in, it redirects the user back to the app. However, the popup, allowing to chose with which app he wants to continue the process, appears. And it's my app which shows up twice. Any idea what might be the reason for that? I tested that on many different android devices and the problem persists.
PS. I am developing the app with an expo. I've also ejected the project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, also in an ejected expo app. Issue is that there are two intents handling your auth login url scheme. For me the issue was that I defined my own intent with a scheme and used *WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync* for popping up a browser window, while at the same time this same scheme was configured in default config for *appAuthRedirectScheme* in build.gradle. This created another intent with the same scheme.
I simply changed the scheme for *appAuthRedirectScheme* to something else...